# Javah not found error

Tags: java, fedora, java-7

I had installed Java 7 in fedora but when i tried **javah** from command prompt it is showing as **javah:command not found** where as javac,java else are working. When i searched in /usr/bin, executables are there for javac,java,javaws but not for javah. Javah is visible in Java/JDK/bin folder. How can i run javah command.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you set up environment variables?

Comment: You can find out if it is on your system somewhere with: `locate javah`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either type the full path of the file (or add that folder where it's in) to your path environment variable using `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/java/JDK/bin/folder`. To have that permanently in your path you could add that line to your .bashrc.

Comment: This answer no longer applies to Java versions newer than Java 8. See my answer below about using `javac -h` instead.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone using more recent versions of java (this post is 6 years old as of my writing this) `javah` no longer exists in the your Java/JDK/bin folder. Instead, use the command `javac -h`